# Как узнать директорию откуда запустили программу?

Tags: c

Как узнать из какой директории запустили программу?

Comment: *Обычно* в `main(argc, argv)` значение `argv[0]` — полное имя выполняемой программы, с указанием каталога...

Comment: ¿Тут имеется ввиду, путь к папке, где лежит .exe, или текущая папка на момент запуска?

Comment: @user7860670 текущая папка на момент запуска

Comment: В общем случае это узнать невозможно, так как у дочернего процесса можно назначить произвольную текущую папку.

Comment: `getcwd()` (на винде - `_getcwd()`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Тогда надо измнить вопрос, он не о текущем каталоге.